# How to create Android image slider like in example

Tags: android, image, slider

I got specific request to create on upper half of my activity image slider like this:

[image]

Difference from image is that I'd only have 2 items on each side.

Each image is clickable item that should open in it's own activity.

Does anyone know ready made free slider like this?

I've never seen such thing on android, nor I know what to search for.

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something called CarouselLayout but with some modifications. Just google it or look at a post a guy recently posted on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424296/android-carousel

Comment: In the end, carousel is a bit different then this, I needed cowerflow, but Carousel is also good thing.